# Change Windows browser proxy settings via ruby script

Tags: windows, ruby, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I'm looking for some code/library to programmatically change proxy settings for popular browsers using Ruby on Windows.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Internet Explorer** the settings are stored in the Registry (under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.) Look for `ProxyServer`, `ProxyOverride` etc. so these could be modified using [Win32::Registry](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/Win32API/rdoc/classes/Win32/Registry.html). e.g.

```
require 'win32/registry'    

proxy = "proxy goes here"
Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open(
  "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\",
  Win32::Registry::KEY_WRITE) do |reg|
    reg.write("ProxyServer",Win32::Registry::REG_SZ, proxy)
end
```

For **Firefox** you would need to determine which profile you wanted to change and could then modify the `prefs.js` file. However if Firefox was running at the time then I don't think it wouldn pickup your your change and would rewrite the prefs file with the original value on exiting.

Comment: @mikej is there a way how to notify IE about the changes?

Comment: Will this change the proxy while Ruby is running watir (ie) in Windows?