# Is it possible to make watir (IE) go through a proxy?

Tags: ruby, proxy, watir

I know that it's possible to set up Privoxy and then control which proxy is in use in the script, but I can't seem to find anything about a native proxy support for Watir.

Any help?

Comment: Do you want to change proxies while the script is running?

Comment: It's been asked and answered already - click this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904670/change-windows-browser-proxy-settings-via-ruby-script

Comment: @DaveMcNulla if that is what he wants to do :)

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin how would you change proxies while script is running via Ruby and ie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Watir runs on the same system as the browser it is driving.  If you want the browser to go through a proxy, then you just set it up that wan under the network settings in the browser options (the same way you would if you were using the browser manually.

if that does not address your question, you might need to make it clearer what you are trying to accomplish